# Django 2.1.X: (models.E026) The model cannot have more than one field with 'primary_key=True'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm, django-migrations

I am currently upgrading a legacy Django app from version **1.11** to **3.2**.

In order to minimize risks I am upgrading one minor version at a time. That means: 1.11 --> 2.0 --> 2.1, etc.

When upgrading from version **2.0.13** to **2.1.15** I have encountered the following error when attempting to open the Django shell:

```
python manage.py shell_plus
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:
   
ERRORS:
myapp.DemoModel: (models.E026) The model cannot have more than one field with 'primary_key=True'.
```

Here is my model:

```
class DemoModel(models.Model):
    field_a = models.OneToOneField(ModelA, models.DO_NOTHING, primary_key=True)
    field_b = models.OneToOneField(ModelB, models.DO_NOTHING, primary_key=True)
    creation_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'demo_model'
        unique_together = (('field_a', 'field_b'),)
```

How could I fix this? **Django shell has worked with all versions prior to Django 2.1.**

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards,

Comment: Your `unique_together` and `primary_key` conditions are *"mutually exclusive"*

Comment: @Atenea_v10 so how did u fix that?